# How to keep the same format as original file when writing a JSON file

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I tried out the functionality of the R package `jsonlite` and not sure why the writting function modifies a bit the structure of the file.

Below is a simple example of a file with a given specific structure. I read it and then write it back to disk, but something minor changes and I cannot open it with the 3rd party app that created it in the first place.

```r
library(jsonlite)

json_lst <- fromJSON(txt = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/valentinitnelav/test/master/test.json")
write_json(json_lst, "./test/test_2.json")
```

Could you help me understand what exactly changes and fix this issue?

I opened the two files with the Mozzila browser and it might be that some lists lose some elements somehow (get "unlisted" possibly, but not all). maybe something happens during the `toJSON()` operation, but not sure what exactly.

Comment: keys can get re-ordered across implementations, but you shouldn't be losing elements.

Comment: @dandavis, is this an issue with `jsonlite` package when writing a JSON file? The answer of @r2evans seems to solve my problem, and when I read both files in R, they are identical. I hope all is good so far, because I have hundreds of these files and I don't want some hidden issue :D

Comment: that all makes sense, i wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front, add `auto_unbox = TRUE`.

`jsonlite`'s default behavior is to strictly "box" vectors of length 1.

```r
toJSON(list(a=1))
# {"a":[1]} 
toJSON(list(a=1), auto_unbox=TRUE)
# {"a":1}
```

So for your code, use

```r
write_json(json_lst, "./test/test_2.json", auto_unbox = TRUE)
```